# Entityframework 4.3 codefirst using TPT and discriminator

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, table-per-type, discriminator

I have these three models:

```
public class Equipment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

}

[Table("Vessels")]
public class Vessel:Equipment
{
    public string Size { get; set; }

}

[Table("Tubes")]
public class Tube : Equipment
{
    public string Pressure{ get; set; }

}
```

I want to show a list of Equipments with 2 columns title and type.

for example:

```
Title        Type
------       -------
101-1        vessel
101-2        vessel
102-3        tube
```

I don't know how to make a discriminator column in Equipments to show the type of each equipments.

**EDITED**

If I have a discriminator in Equipment entity like:

```
public class Equipment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type{ get; set; }  //as discriminator
}
```

I can get the query in controller or repository like this:

```
var equipments=from e in db.Equipments
               select e;
```

Comment: How is your last query dependent on discriminator?

Comment: thank you very much, I think I know where was my mistake. I wanna the Type (discriminator) fill automatically like TPH, but now understand I have to set value in code in every instances I will get from vessel and tube. Thanks a lot @LadislavMrnka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make discriminator column in terms of EF mapping - TPT inheritance doesn't support it because the discriminator is a subtable. You can try to use something like:

```
public abstract class Equipment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public abstract string Type { get; }
}
```

and override `Type` property in subtypes to get the correct name. You will not be able to use that property in Linq-to-Entities queries because it is not mapped.

Comment: thanks for replying, I've read your comment in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142214/can-i-specify-a-discriminator-column-with-a-table-per-type-mapping),both are nice and helpful, but I didn't understand how I can bring that query out from my dbcontext. I will edit my question plz take a look at the end of my question.