# How to query for entities of all types but one in a table per hierarchy?

Tags: entity-framework-6, table-per-hierarchy, oftype

I'm trying to do something that would seem very simple.  I want to query for all types in a table per hierarchy, except for one type. This has to run as a single (pageable) database query.

To return a single type, I can call `IQueryable<T>.OfType<T>()`. I don't see any way to pass a subset of types. As far as I know, the Discriminator cannot be exposed as a model property, so I cannot filter with any kind of `Where(x => x.Discriminator != value)` call.

Someone suggested something like `IQueryable<T>.Where(x => x is Type1 || x is Type2 || x is Type3)`, but I recall that kind of structure not working right.  Someone also suggested using `OfType` for each type, joined by `Union` calls, but I think that would produce a poorer performing query than necessary when I'm trying to filter a single type from many types (e.g. exclude only 1 of 20 types, using 18 unions).

Is there a known way to perform such a query that I'm missing?

Comment: I really don't want to have to rely on something like adding an 'Exclude' property to the base table type and flagging it false for everything but the one type I want to exclude.  It's an inflexible approach (e.g. what if I need to exclude one type in one context, but two other types in another context... I'd need yet another dedicated property).

Comment: You see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142214/can-i-specify-a-discriminator-column-with-a-table-per-type-mapping) and [this](https://www.interworks.com/blog/banderton/2011/04/15/querying-specifc-inheritance-types-entity-framework)?